# localhost/phpmyadmin root password recovery in ubuntu

Tags: password, phpmyadmin

I have recently installed phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.4 but when I go to localhost/phpmyadmin to login and enter user as root and password it will generate the error Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword) and please provide me the solution to reset password and show the existing password

Answer (score 1):

Without having to restart MySQL, in the default Debian installation (and I assume in Ubuntu too) there is an administrative user with every power that you can use to recover your root password (it is normally used by packages configuration scripts). You can have a MySQL shell with the command:

```
mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

Then you can use the same query as suggested by Andy to reset the password.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps to reset your password:

> sudo service mysql stop
>
> sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
>
> mysql -u root mysql

Change *strong-passwd* with the **new password**:

> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('strong-passwd') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
>
> sudo pkill mysqld
>
> sudo service mysql start

The above will:

- stop MySql server
- start mysqld
- login as root
- update password
- kill mysqld
- start MySQL server

Will will be able to login after that.

Comment: when I run (sudo service mysql stop ) it will ask for my pc password but it will not be entered and when I run UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('strong-passwd') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit; it will generate an error bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' please provide me solution to this error.

Comment: "ask for my pc password but it will not be entered" -> it will but is not displaying the characters that you type in the console. Regarding the second part of the question, this is because, after you put your "pc" password you will get to the mysql prompt (>). There is where you type the UPDATE command. Bash will throw an error as it does not know that format.

Comment: so when I write the update command it will throw an error as it does not know that format instead of this command which command will be used to update the password

Comment: You have to update/reset the password while inside MySQL prompt. As stated above, you will have > as prompt when you are connected to MySQL. Once there, issue the UPDATE command.

Comment: when I run the command sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables & mysql -u root mysql it will generate this error                      [1] 5682
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
dev-11@dev11-System-Product-Name:~$ 140923 17:34:00 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.

Comment: Please post the output of: *ps -ef | grep mysql*

Comment: dev-11    5749  5622  0 17:43 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql above command results this output

Comment: OK. It's not running. Type **sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &** hit ENTER, then run the rest of the commands.

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
it will again results this error as I run update comand

Comment: @VijaySharma please read my comments. You are still trying to issue the UPDATE command in bash. It will not work. Make sure that: 1)mysql service is stopped; 2) you start mysqld with --skip-grant-tables option and send the process in background (&). Then run the rest of commands.

Comment: andy please tell where to write the update command I have to write the command in terminal or any other place

Comment: @VijaySharma have a look @ http://imgur.com/UqMf7p6

Comment: -~$ sudo service mysql stop
[sudo] password for dev-11: 
stop: Unknown instance: 
-:~$ sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables &
-:~$ 140923 18:27:06 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
[1]+Exit1 sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables
-:~$ mysql -u root mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
dev-11@dev11-:~$ when I run command given by you in @imgur.com/UqMf7p6 this output result will be shown

Comment: Most likely you have rogue mysqld running still in background after your attempts. You need to **sudo pkill mysqld** , make sure you are able to start the server normally, then check the image send to you.